# RUBY : Unexpected end of file and command not found?

Tags: ruby, macos

I start to learn Ruby and i got some problem when i ran the code on the 
Terminal. it says :

```
desktop/RUBY/boucles.rb: line 1: voyages: command not found
desktop/RUBY/boucles.rb: line 14: syntax error: unexpected end of file.
```

My IDE is sublim text.

How i can solve that ?

```
voyages = [
  { ville: "Paris", duree: 10 },
  { ville: "New York", duree: 5 },
  { ville: "Berlin", duree: 2 },
  { ville: "Montreal", duree: 15 }
]

voyages.each do |voyage|
  if voyage[:duree] <= 5
    puts "Voyage à #{voyage[:ville]} de #{voyage[:duree]} jours"
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to run `rails c`, first - so that you're in a rails console. If you want any possible changes to your database to be rolled back upon `exit`, then do `rails c --sandbox`. In the rails console, your code runs just fine.

Comment: i ran it into rails console but stills doesn't work

Comment: The next two line are empty there is nothing so i don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those errors look like they might be coming from your shell, not from Ruby!

How are you running this script? You should be running `ruby boucles.rb` in your terminal.

Comment: Wow ! thank you, that's working now! it's because I didn't write 'ruby' just only the directory before... like this (ruby  desktop/RUBY/boucles.rb) , it works! thanks a lot! rookie mistakes

Comment: You're welcome! Because you were just running a file path, and your script has no [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)), your terminal was probably defaulting to try run it as a shell script. By putting `ruby` first you're saying that you want to run the **ruby** executable with that particular script.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct and works without any syntax errors. If you were editing in Sublime Text, you might want to make sure that you saved the file first.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your help. I saved the file everytime with cmd + S but still doesn't work.